# how to get parent object property in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, nested

I've been searching a way to get the Parent object property in a nested Object but had no luck.

Here is the nested object I am using:

```
var obj = {
        name: 'My Name',
        obj1: {
                 age: 18,
                 name: this.name
            }
    };
```

But it gives and `undefined` error.

Is there any way in JavaScript or jQuery to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And with some jQuery love, I achieved it.

Here is the original one I was using:

```
var obj = {
        name: 'My Name',
        obj1: {
                 age: 18,
                 name: this.name
            }
    };
```

And here is my trick:

I created another object `obj1Copy`:

```
var obj1Copy = {
    name: obj.name
};
```

See I am using the parent object name instead of `this` in this copy.
And then use the jQuery `$.extend` to merge them:

```
var newObj = $.extend(obj.obj1, obj1Copy);
```

And then use the `newObj` instead of `obj1`, like `newObj.name` would return `My Name`.

If there's any better and easy way then please share.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this :

```
var obj = new obj();

function obj(){
    var self = this;
    self.name = 'My Name';
    self.obj1 = {
        age: 18,
        name: self.name
    }
};
```